# How to install visual studio installer projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation

I downloaded "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects" on my computer. And when I try to install it I face "Setup Blocked" message.
And the reason describes in this way:

"Microsoft Visual Studio is required, but it is not installed on this computer. Please install it and retry."

While I've already have "VS Express 2013 for Desktop". What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

VS Express editions [do not support extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Extensibility).
http://msmvps.com/blogs/carlosq/archive/2014/05/07/visual-studio-express-edition-doesn-t-support-extensions-despite-its-extension-manager.aspx

You can try a separate tool to create the setup packages, like [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com), is has a [free edition](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html) too. Or Wix Toolset if you prefer the hard way, i.e.scripting.

**EDIT**

Indeed, as Micky Duncan mentioned, this seems to apply only for third-party extensions.

However, now Microsoft has made available the free [VS community edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx), which is practically equivalent with the Professional edition features wise. If you can meet the EULA terms access to all these features is now free.

Comment: Incorrect.  VS2013 Express editions [do not support **3rd party** extensions](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/05/21/no-extensions-for-visual-studio-express.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea on Visual Studio Express version since I'm using Visual Studio Community version (which is totally free today, I strongly recommend it) you better use "Extensions" menu item inside the Visual Studio and try to install from there. It will work like a charm.